# Is it possible to specify 2 Cognito user pools with auth annotation in schema.graphql in Amplify?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I have a question about Amplify, especially, how to

- connect two Amazon Cognito user pools from the same API(AppSync)
- define in which Amazon Cognito user pool authentication is required in schema.graphql.

The following picture is what I want to achieve.
Some API require `user pool for user` authentication, but on the other hand, others require `user pool for admin`.

- API's have to be able to see the same Dynamo DB.

[image: Example]

Comment: Appsync does support multiple cognito user pools , but unfortunately amplify does not support it , see there is currently open issue right now https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/4853

Answer (score 0):

Amplify doesn't support multiple user pools. However, you could achieve something similar using user groups: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/auth/groups

Then when you're working with the API, you could use authorization rules: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/auth#multiple-authorization-rules

There's a blog post about it here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/aws-amplify-allows-you-to-mix-and-match-authorization-modes-in-datastore/